# Solve discontinuous ODE with lsode

Tags: matlab, numerics, ode, r, octave

I am trying to solve a discontinuous ODE using the [lsode](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/deSolve/versions/1.36/topics/lsode) solver. I tried setting the `t_crit` parameter to specify the time where the discontinuity is present, but it didn't help.

The analytical solution of the ODE looks like the following, where the discontinuity appears at $t = -0.433$, which is the value I set to the `t_crit` parameter of [lsode](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/deSolve/versions/1.36/topics/lsode). Is there any strategy to tackle this kind of situations with [lsode](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/deSolve/versions/1.36/topics/lsode)?

[image]

Please note that I am restricted to using [lsode](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/deSolve/versions/1.36/topics/lsode) as the solver.

Answer (score 2):

If you speak of discontinuous ODE, one would think of a discontinuous right side function. If the discontinuity is only a jump, and only depends on time, then using the `t_crit` parameter will divide the integration into two pieces there, each piece a well-defined integration task.

What you have here is a singularity in the ODE. One strategy to integrate over the end of the solution is to divide the ODE into a system for the parts of the fraction $y=\frac{u}{v}$, where the system for $(u,v)$ is not singular.

Example: The model Riccati equation $y'=x^2+y^2$. Inserting the fraction gives
$$
u'v-uv'=x^2v^2+u^2\\
\iff
(u'-x^2v)v=u(v'+u)
$$
The non-trivial (and only) case is for the linear system
$$
u'=x^2v\\
v'=-u
$$
This has continuous coefficients, can thus be integrated without bounds. The singularity of the original equations occurs at the roots of $v$.

Comment: Thank you Lutz for your answer!
I'm still processing the strategy you suggest and I wonder if y = u/v is just a change of variable? Or something I should come up with?

Comment: If and how you can use such a de-singularization idea depends on the differential equation. For some, for instance Riccati type DE, it will be natural, for others it may not work at all.